# Including file known to already be included

Tags: c++, c, header, include, convention

What's the convention when including a file you know is already included by another include?

Example: 
Class Base is declared in "base.h" and has a few child classes.  Base has a virtual method foo(Bar& bar) and therefore includes "bar.h".  From a proper convention standpoint, should we include "bar.h" in the child classes as well, given that the child classes include "base.h", which includes "bar.h"?

Comment: I believe that this is an opinion question and it will be closed as such. Anyways, I try to make all of my headers include only what they absolutely need but do not worry so much about the topic of your question.

Comment: Sidenote: If base.h doesn't refer to definitions in bar.h in any other way than that, then you don't need to include bar.h in base.h at all. Declaring `class Bar` is sufficient.

Comment: I don't buy the "and therefore". I might  write this like so: `class Bar; class Foo { virtual Bar & f() = 0; };`

Comment: One train of thought is to is to include all headers containing declarations and definitions the contents of your header requires regardless if they are included by other headers. The reason for this is that if headers change what they include they don't require other code to be updated.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262019/is-it-good-practice-to-rely-on-headers-being-included-transitively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the declaration of a function only requires the parameters to be declared, you'll need to include the corresponding header. For known base classes or types of non-`private` data members the definition needs ro be included. Since everything else either only requires a declaration or is an implementation detail, you shouldn't rely on indirect headers being included.

Answer (score 1):

One school of thought is that including both base.h and bar.h in child.h is better. Even though this is a virtual function dependency, including bar.h points future developer (who might not have an IDE) into the declaration without having to read base.h.

For non-virtual function, including both should be better imho, since another developer can change the content of base.h without having to worry about child.h's dependency on bar.h.